# Проверьте правильность построения предложения

Tags: запятые

> Мне нравятся люди с похожими на мои, интересами.

Правильно ли построено предложение и стоит запятая?

Answer (score 1):

> **2.** Не обособляются распространенные определения:
> **1)** стоящие перед существительным и не имеющие добавочных обстоятельственных оттенков значения: *Дарья Александровна стояла среди **разбросанных по комнате** вещей* (Л. Т.); *За столом рылся в книгах **приехавший недавно из станицы** счетовод* (Ш.)...

Распространенное определение *похожими на мои* стоит **перед** определяемым словом *интересами* (от него и задается вопрос к определительному обороту; интересами — какими?), поэтому запятая не ставится. Такие конструкции встречаются, и не редко.

*Ведь тем, чем я занимался в последнее время, и что теперь для меня навсегда, наверно, окажется утерянным, дало мне большие надежды и массу информации касательно того, что в этом мире кроме меня существуют ещё люди **с похожими на мои взглядами*** (Александр Субботин. Сделка Политова).

*Я не принадлежал самому себе и требовал у родителей, чтобы нашли мне подобных, ведь есть же такие люди **с похожими на мои страдания муками**, ведь как-то это должно исчезнуть, может, они знают* (Сергей Васильев. Страна мучительных грез).

[Согласованные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108)
[Оборот перед определяемым существительным](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC/)

*Дай мне в руки инструкции или скрижаль,

**как построить похожий на твой дирижабль**,

как мне выйти из сна за барьер световой,

как стать равным тебе и быть рядом с тобой.*
О. Благодатова. Весною

Comment: Второй пример не в тему, там нет пропуска существительного.

Comment: Не редко? В Нацкорпусе 0 результатов.

Comment: А где у нас третий пример? И где, собственно, какой-то пропуск?

Comment: Второй, исправлено. Пропуск заключается в следующем: *с похожими на мои [взгляды] взглядами*.

Comment: Определяемое слово перед оборотом: ...ведь есть же такие люди **с муками**, похожими на мои страдания. А определяемое слово в предложении часто стоит после оборота, именно это — не редкость.

Comment: Здесь вся загвоздка в этом пропуске, из-за него согласование не стыкуется (*на мои интересами*). Ведь сначала используют слово, а потом пропускают, а здесь наоборот. Вот так норм: *с интересами, похожими на мои*.

Comment: А похоже, что "похожими на мои" перед существительным не редкость. И дальше ведь идут примеры с этой фразой. А другое нелогично, ведь причастные обороты перед существительным — это обычное явление, нет смысла говорить, что они встречаются и тем более что не редко. Всё-таки надо сказать о пропуске слова до его использования. Это не норма.

Answer (score 0):

Нормально составлено, а запятая не нужна.

Comment: Не нормально, надо так: *Мне нравятся люди с интересами, похожими на мои.* Потому что сначала употребление, а потом пропуск, а не: *Мне нравятся люди с  похожими на мои [интересы] интересами.*

Comment: Да нет, так вроде тоже говорят. А то, что у тебя в скобках, опускают.

Comment: Не слышал, мне немного слух режет, так точно не идеально.

Comment: А идеала вообще не существует. ;)

Comment: Да ладно. Не путай с совершенством. Идеал — это то, к чему нельзя придраться. "Не идеально" там подразумевает "не очень хорошо".